# Using .getSpeedLimit() also makes warning sounds . How to Override?

Tags: android, here-api

Unable to override Here SDK to disable sound effect on the onSpeedExceeded event.

Using the Here Developer tutorial, (https://developer.here.com/blog/android-premium-sdk-speed-limit-warning-example), I succeeded in running the sample app. But...

While driving, when I exceed the speed limit, there is a doot doot doot.  I want to override this behaviour as I intend to use my own sounds.

I guessed that I might override the code by creating a NavigationManager.SpeedWarningListener.  Unfortunately I can not disable or defeat the 'onSpeedExceeded' sound effects.

```
NavigationManager.SpeedWarningListener speedWarningListener = new NavigationManager.SpeedWarningListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSpeedExceeded(String s, float v) {
        //super.onSpeedExceeded(s, v);
        //Log.v(Global.TAG, "onSpeedExceeded");
        Global.SpeedLimitExceeded = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSpeedExceededEnd(String s, float v) {
        //super.onSpeedExceededEnd(s, v);
        //Log.v(Global.TAG, "onSpeedExceededEnd");
        Global.SpeedLimitExceeded = false;
    }
};
```

EDITED ANSWER: This method needs to be amended to stop the speed warning:

```
private void startNavigationManager() {
    NavigationManager.Error navError = NavigationManager.getInstance().startTracking();

    // added by suggestion from stackoverflow
    NavigationManager.getInstance().stopSpeedWarning();

    if (navError != NavigationManager.Error.NONE) {
        Log.d(Global.TAG, "NavigationManager: false");
        //handle error navError.toString());
    } else {
        //Log.d(Global.TAG, "NavigationManager: true");
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please help to elaborate if you completely disable voice navigation or only the speeding warning needs to be disabled.

Comment: In my question, I mention that I used the sample tutorial code.  It does not use voice navigation.  It only shows current speed and current speedlimit.

And the sound comes probably from just asking .getSpeedLimit or .getSpeed

So I guess all I want is to disable the speed warning.  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set speedWarningEnabled accordingly for NMANavigationManager
navigationManager:didUpdateSpeedingStatus:forCurrentSpeed:speedLimit: will be sent to the delegate when speeding is detected or when a correction is made.

Also refer http://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMANavigationManager.html

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'll add the code into my app later today

Comment: This pointed me in the correct direction. For those following, I've updated my question to include my amended code